# C# Static methods and Console

Tags: c#, methods, static, console

hi i have a **static** method in a class , in my console application i use like as this

```
Console.writeLine("Some thing Some thing");

Console.writeLine("Some thing Some thing");

String X=ClassName.Method(Para); <--- Check here


Console.writeLine("Some thing after some thing ");

Console.writeLine("Some thing after some thing ");
```

My problem is After execution of the **static method** code after that are not get executed after getting the return value of the statc method application is like halted .. how to overcome this ?

Comment: this is not normal behaviour. give us more code pls

Comment: What does "like halted" mean?

Comment: Have you tried a try/catch or debugging and stepping into the static function?

Comment: Instead of showing us pseudo code, please show us the real code that calls your static method and also the static method itself.

Comment: What does `String X=ClassName.Method(Para);` do?

Comment: code after *static method call * that are not get executed

Comment: @Adrian it just returns a string

Comment: show us the code of the .Method()

Comment: @Sudantha, well that I can tell! I meant: what does it do in its contents? Show us code...

Comment: You must debug and check , there must be some ambigous thing happpening inside function...

Comment: yea i think a exception is trown inside that class and its was not visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method might be throwing an exception or blocking (not returning).

To tell if an exception is thrown, put a try/catch around your method and print out any exceptions in the catch block.

```
try
{    
String X=ClassName.Method(Para); <--- Check here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}", e);
}
```

If your method is simply not returning (e.g. it could be blocked on a Console.ReadLine) then you will need to step through in the debugger to see why.

Also, if this is the first time the "ClassName" class is being accessed, you might be running a static constructor ("type constructor").  Sometimes it's not obvious that type constructor code is being run, but if you're doing something which might block there, this could also be your problem, not just the "Method" method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with halting the application lies in the `ClassName.Method(Para)` call, if that method blocks your application you should look further in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find if any thing wrong is happening inside the calling function :

```
Console.writeLine("Some thing Some thing");    
Console.writeLine("Some thing Some thing");    

try
{    
String X=ClassName.Method(Para); <--- Check here
}    

catch(Exception e)
{
Console.writeLine(e.Message);
}

Console.writeLine("Some thing after some thing ");    
Console.writeLine("Some thing after some thing ");
```